# Derivative Calculation $\Delta(x\cdot\nabla u) = \color{red}{2}\Delta u + x \cdot (\nabla(\Delta u))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

$\Delta(x\cdot\nabla u) = \Delta u + x \cdot (\nabla(\Delta u))$

Does this hold for $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and $u : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ ? If it does, why does it?

I calculated the above formula by writing out all the variables from $x_1$ to $x_n$ and guessing that it must be correct. But I am not familiar with 'direct' calculations using $\nabla$ and $\Delta$, so I need some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no standard writing of the derivative of a vector field I don't know of a way to do this in a coordinate free manner. I'm coming to the following result which is different from your formula.

The $j$ in the calculation is fixed, and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. I write $x_i$ for the $i^{\rm th}$ component of $x$ and $u_{.i}$ for the partial derivative of the scalar function $u$ with respect to $x_i$. Then
$$\eqalign{
{\partial\over\partial x_j}\left(\sum_i x_i u_{.i}\right)&=
\sum_i\bigl(\delta_{ij} u_{.i}+x_i u_{.ij}\bigr)\cr
 &=u_{.j}+\sum_ix_i u_{.ij}\ .\cr}$$
Doing this a second time we obtain
$$\eqalign{
{\partial^2\over\partial x_j^2}\left(\sum_i x_i u_{.i}\right)&=
u_{.jj}+{\partial\over\partial x_j}\sum_ix_i u_{.ij}\cr
&=u_{.jj}+\sum_i\bigl(\delta_{ij}u_{.ij}+ x_i u_{.ijj}\bigr)\cr
&=2u_{.jj}+\sum_i x_i u_{.ijj}\ .\cr}$$
Summing over $j$ we find that in fact
$$\Delta(x\cdot \nabla u)=2\Delta u+x\cdot\nabla(\Delta u)\ .\tag{1}$$
Note that in the one-dimensional case we have
$$\bigl(x u'(x)\bigr)''=\bigl(u'(x)+x u''(x)\bigr)'=2u''(x)+x\bigl(u'(x)\bigr)''\ ,$$
as obtained in $(1)$.